# Error while inserting data into SQLiteDatabase in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I initial object db and called its method from my current class:

```
        db = new DBHelper(context);
        db.addCallerInfo(FragmentCaller.iName.getText().toString(),
                FragmentCaller.sex.getSelectedItemPosition(),
                FragmentCaller.iAddress.getText().toString(),
                FragmentCaller.iTel.getText().toString(),
                FragmentCaller.callerType.getSelectedItemPosition(),
                FragmentCaller.iSpecify.getText().toString());
```

**In DBhelper class:**

```
public void addCallerInfo(String name,int   sex ,String address,String  tel,int  callerType_id,String  specify) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put("name", name);
        values.put("sex", sex);
        values.put("address", address);
        values.put("tel", tel);
        values.put("specify", specify);
        values.put("callerType_id", callerType_id);
        db.insert(TableHelper.TABLE_callerInfo, null, values);
    }
```

Then it has problem `java.lang.NullPointerException:`

Attempt to invoke virtual method `long android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, android.content.ContentValues)` on a null object reference

Help please! Thanks.

Comment: your **db** is null check it

Comment: I think it is init?
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        this.db = db;
}

Comment: onCreate method only called when your database create for first time. so when your restart the app, value of db will be null.

Answer (score 2):

Add below line in **addCallerInfo()** method. Then you can insert **contentValues** into Data Base.

```
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
```

Comment: Thanks. I added this line it worked

Comment: Glad to help u. Can you accept this as answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can't declare the `Database` type `Writable` or `Readable`

First declare it then `inserting values` like this:

```
 SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();

And For just Readable database

 SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
```